# pagination doesn't work in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I have successfully created pagination on some of the pages on the application on which I am working with, but I can't make it on this one:

I have 7 records in the database, and when 
page is displayed all 7 records are displayed instead of 5, as I would like to be.

Sure enough, links for the paging are not displayed.

Here is my controller code:

```
public function displayAllFaqCategories()
    {

         //initializing & configuring paging

        $currentUser = $this->isLoggedIn();
        $this->load->model('faqCategoriesModel');
        $this->db->order_by('sorder');
        $limit = 5;
        $offset = 3;

        $offset = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->db->limit(5, $offset);

        $data['faq_categories'] = $this->faqCategoriesModel->selectCategoriesAndParents();
        $totalresults = $this->db->get('faq_categories')->num_rows();

        //initializing & configuring paging
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = site_url('/backOfficeUsers/faqcategories');
        $config['total_rows'] = $totalresults;
        $config['per_page'] = 5;
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;


        $this->pagination->initialize($config); 

        $errorMessage = '';
        $data['main_content'] = 'faq/faqcategories';
        $data['title'] = 'FAQ Categories';

        $this->load->vars($data,$errorMessage);
        $this->load->vars($currentUser);
        $this->load->view('backOffice/template');

    } // end of function displayAllFaqCategories
```

And here is my model function code:

```
public function selectCategoriesAndParents($selectWhat = array())
   {    
       $data = array();
       $query = $this->db->query("SELECT fq . * , COALESCE( fqp.$this->parent_name,  '0' ) AS parentname
                                  FROM $this->table_name AS fq
                                  LEFT OUTER JOIN $this->table_name AS fqp ON fqp.catid = fq.parentid"); 
       if($query->num_rows() > 0) 
       {
           foreach($query->result_array() as $row) 
               {
                   $data[] = $row;  
               }
           }           
       $query->free_result();
       return $data;
   } // end of function selectCategoriesAndParents
```

In the view, bellow of the table with the records I have the following code:

```
 <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links();?>
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Regards,Zoran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mixed two different things together I think. You're partially using the ActiveRecord class of CI, but then running the query yourself.

The simplest change would be:

```
    // get all the rows
    $data['faq_categories'] = $this->faqCategoriesModel->selectCategoriesAndParents();
    // figure out the count of all of them
    $totalresults = count($data['faq_categories']);
    // only take some of the rows of the array, instead of keeping all of them and then showing all 7 of your records
    $data['faq_categories'] = array_splice($data['faq_categories'], $offset, $limit);
```

Hopefully that should fix it!

To further explain what the original problem is, I think when you run this:

```
$totalresults = $this->db->get('faq_categories')->num_rows();
```

It takes the previous line `$this->db->limit(5, $offset);` into account, so it only returns 5 rows. Then, when you tell the pagination library that you only want to show 5 per page, the library thinks that it is actually showing all the results, so there is no need for pagination links!

Answer (score 0):

Edit like this

```
$offset = $this->uri->segment(3) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
```

Comment: I change the code like this: //$offset = $this->uri->segment(3);
            $offset = $this->uri->segment(3) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0; and result remain the same, all 7 records are displayed and no pagination links...

Comment: NO..??wat is the value of $Totalpages..??